# Laravel Commands CSRF verification failed

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I'm having a problem in using cron for Laravel Command, whenever the function is executed `php /path/to/artisan/ command:cron` it results to `CSRF verification failed`.

Is there any resolved on how to disable the CSRF Verification on Laravel Commands? 
I found a document about route disabling CSRF verification, but I need for commands.

Comment: you can pass csrf token as inputs. did you tried that?

Comment: @KevinRED, I know that way. But mine's was executed from the cronjob not from a web page.

Comment: is it post method ? are you using `routr` cron job ?

Comment: Why are you trying to execute the controller function from command ? Its better if you can have separate function for commands and in that case, you don't need the CSRF token.

Comment: Sorry, misworded. I meant, the Laravel Command, I added another function on the Command named `send()` that the `function handle()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude like :

```
 protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
```

For More details plz see 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: This doesn't work, it only works for routed laravel controllers not laravel commands